# What differences are there between the Opteka 6.5mm and Rokinon 8mm fisheye for Nikon?

Tags: lens, samyang

I have heard these two lenses are the same. Are they just made by the same company (Samyang) or are the physically the exact same lens? If not, what differences are there, physically and optically? Also why is the Opteka $150 while the Rokinon is $240?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Opteka 6.5mm, Vivitar 7mm, Samyang/Rokinon/Bower/Pro-Optic/Phoenix/Walimex 8mm fisheye lens for dSLRs are all the same lens optically, and are all made by Samyang in Korea. The external differences are going to be in the casing and branding and (obviously) the [flange focal distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flange_focal_distance) for the specific mount. And between different mount versions, the direction the rings rotate and aperture control from the camera (Canon versions don't allow it; I believe Nikon versions do if you lock the lens to f/22).

The difference in price, I would assume, basically come down to different retailers and distribution chains.

Comment: So both will have the same effective focal length and distortion when used on the same camera?

Comment: Yes. They should be optically identical. Why they're designated with different focal lengths is anyone's guess.

Comment: Thanks very much. I think I'll go with the Opteka since it's a lot cheaper.